# issue in Routing of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have two modules called Experts and Doctors.
I have created a single controller called ExpertsController.cs to handle both module.
It working good for experts but not for doctors.
I need route path redirect that map all routes to Experts Controller.
And i want to use same views for both.

like. www.website.com/Doctors will be map to /Experts and client will not be aware of this.

like www.website.com/Docotrs/Edit/1 will be map to /Experts/Edit/1 and client will not aware of this. and browser will show www.website.com/Docotrs/Edit/1  in address bar

Currently i am using this code:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ExpertsRoute",
           url: "Experts/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Experts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Doctor = false }
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "DoctorsRoute",
             url: "Doctors/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Experts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Doctor = true }            

         );

        routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Comment: What's happening now?

Comment: it is working fine for index action.. But   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) it is redirecting to Experts/Edit/1
it should take me to Doctors/Edit/1

Comment: Still not clear what's happening and what you want here. The URL WILL still say `experts/edit/1` but route to DoctorsController.Edit(1) - Also, the controller resolved entirely depends on where you're using `HtmlHelper.ActionLink`, since you haven't specified the controller in the call. Please clarfiy your question.

Comment: i am using single controoler for two module..

Comment: want a route that map both controller to single controller..
and show sperate urls for each controller

Comment: i have used above mention code.
it work fine when i request for Experts/ or Doctors/
but when ActionLink for edit resolves, it redirect me to Expert/Edit/1 in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `ActionLink` is picking up the first route with controller = "Experts", action = "Index", which happens to be `ExpertsRoute`. Try using `RouteLink` instead to specify the name of the route you want to use.

**Example**

```
@Html.RouteLink("Bacon", "DoctorsRoute", new { action = "Edit", id = item.id})
```

Comment: receiving this error: 
A route named 'Edit' could not be found in the route collection.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I copied your routes and applied these links to a test page. `@Html.RouteLink("Doctors Edit", "DoctorsRoute", new { action = "Edit", id = 3 })` 
            `@Html.RouteLink("Experts Edit", "ExpertsRoute", new { action = "Edit", id = 4 })`

Comment: it is working fine.
but i have same view. it will be again same for the both of routes